# Inverse Sigmoid Function in Python for Neural Networks?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement an Inverse Sigmoid function to the last layer of my Convolutional Neural Network?
I am trying to build the network in Pytorch and I want to take the output from the last Convolutional Layer and then apply Inverse Sigmoid Function to it.

I have read that the logit function is the opposite of sigmoid function and I tried implementing it but its not working.
I used the logit function from the scipy library and used it in the function.

```
def InverseSigmoid(self, x):

        x = logit(x)
        return x
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean?  There are [many different “sigmoid” functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples).  If the function in question is the logistic function  ↦ 1/(1 + exp(−)), then its inverse is indeed the logit function  ↦ log(/(1 − )).  (For values of  near 1/2, it is better to use the formula −log1p((1 − 2)/), to avoid evaluating log at approximate inputs near 1.)  But we need to know what you observed to go wrong in order to help.

Comment: @FloatingPundit Why should one avoid `log p` near `p = 1`? Both versions seem to give the same result: `assert np.log(1 + 1e-15) == np.log1p(1 + 1e-15 - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Sigmoid is just `1 / (1 + e**-x)`. So if you want to invert it you can just `-ln((1 / x) - 1)`. For numerical stability purposes, you can also do `-ln((1 / (x + 1e-8)) - 1)`. This is the inverse function of sigmoid, implementation is straightforward.

Comment: What is your definition of “numerical stability” (there is no standard definition of the term) that motivates adding 10⁻⁸ to ?  Certainly it doesn't improve forward stability or backward stability, and it doesn't change the conditioning of the logit function—it just makes the algorithm give worse errors in the answers if your goal is to compute logit.

Comment: As @FloatingPundit says, `eps = 1e-8` has no effect on numerical stability. It "avoids" a division by zero when `x = 0`, but it also makes `x = 1` return `nan`. On the other hand, `-ln((1 / x) - 1)` reasonably returns `-inf` and `inf`, for `x = 0` and `x = 1`, respectively. Thus: I recommend *not* adding `1e-8`.

Comment: I wonder if `ln(x) - ln(1 - x)` would be more accurate for the forward pass... It also avoids an explicit division.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse sigmoid may be computed via:

```
inv_sigmoid(x) = ln(x) - ln(1 - x)
```

---

Proof:

```
sigmoid(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

```
inv_sigmoid(sigmoid(x))
  = ln(sigmoid(x)) - ln(1 - sigmoid(x))
  = ln(sigmoid(x) / (1 - sigmoid(x)))
  = -ln((1 - sigmoid(x)) / sigmoid(x))
  = -ln(1 / sigmoid(x) - 1)
  = -ln(1 + exp(-x) - 1)
  = x
```